# Command to run a programm if a specific programm run

Tags: windows, command, task, scheduler

I need to run .vbs program if a specific program lunched. I tried to do it using task scheduler but its not work because my application not write any event to trigger the action on a specific event.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Autoitscript for that. Just create a loop like this:

```
While 1
    If ProcessExists('yourexe.exe') Then Shellexecute(yourVBS...) ...
        Sleep(500)
WEnd
```